# in drupal 7, how to submit a form without redirecting to the comment page or message page?

Tags: forms, drupal, redirect

I have made a message form and comment form as blocks and embedded the blocks in a view, whenever I submit the message / comment form, the page will redirect to the message / comment page.

This is code:

```
 $node = node_load($nid); // $nid contains the node id        
 $comment = new stdClass;
 $comment->nid = arg(2);
 $form = drupal_get_form('comment_node_project_form', $comment);
 print render($form);
```

How should I do to submit the form without redirecting ? on the $form variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are either going to need $form_state['redirect'] (though in this case you may have to  to have to unset it, since your form is already redirecting to a new page) or if you mean to say you don't want to have the page refresh at all, you'll need to ajax-ify your form.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax form submit else using form alter add a custom submit callback where you can redirect the page where you wish to.

Another very primitive approach can be, just change the `$form['action']` value to something like this:

```
$form['#action'] = '?'. drupal_get_destination();
```

This will redirect you back to the page from where the comment was submitted.